# find value of id in jquery

Tags: jquery, cakephp

when I am trying to fetch the value of id, it returns me 0; I want "a". 
Thanks in ADVANCE

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#lettera').click(function(){
       var a = $('#lettera').val();console.log(a);
    });
});
</script>
<section>
   <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
           <ul class="list-inline">
               <?php
                   foreach($alphas as $letter){
                       echo ($this->Html->tag('li', $letter, ['id' => 'letter'.$letter]));
                   }
               ?>
           </ul>
       </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element you're creating appears to be an `li`, and `li` don't have a `value` attribute. Presumably you're looking for the text of the element, so use `text()` instead:

```
$('#lettera').click(function(){
  var a = $(this).text();
  console.log(a);
});
```

Comment: Thanks but how to change id dynamically? if I want to do same for $('#lettera') to $('#letterz') how to do this?

Comment: Well, you really shouldn't as `id` are supposed to be the same throughout the pages lifetime. If you really have to do this you can use the setter of `attr()`, `$(this).attr('id', 'foo');`

Comment: in my case id is dynamic. I have 26 alphabets which belongs to id for a = $('#lettera'), b = $('#letterb')......z = $('#letterz')

Comment: In which case I'd suggest you use a common class to select the elements and then retrieve their id in the click handler

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
 var a = $('#lettera').val()
```

to

```
var a = $('#lettera').attr("id")
```

Comment: This won't work - this will return `lettera` - the OP wants the text content (not the "value" as he states)

Comment: What's the point in selecting the element by its `id`, just to retrieve the `id`, which you already have?

Comment: so all he need is to replace "'letter'.$letter" with "$letter"